# Mybatis resultmap unable to map String type

Tags: mybatis, resultset

```
<mapper namespace="EmployeeMapper">
<resultMap id="employeeResultMap"
           type="EmployeeInfo">
    <result property="employeeId" column="current.employee_id"/>
    <result property="employeeName" column="current.employee_name"/>
    <result property="job" column="current.job"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getEmployeeData" parameterType="list" resultMap="employeeResultMap">
    SELECT current.employee_id, emp.employee_name , current.job
    FROM Employees emp join Jobs current on emp.employee_id = 
     current.employee_id 
</select>
```

EmployeeId is integer and employee name is string.
But EmployeeId is mapping correctly, while employee name is getting mapped to null. If I change query to

```
SELECT current.employee_id as employeeId, emp.employee_name as employeeName, 
current.job as job
FROM Employees emp join Jobs current on emp.employee_id = 
 current.employee_id
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `current.` from resultMap. The value for `column` property must match the column name from SQL query (case insensitive), underscore to camel case name mapping is also done by default.

If you remove both `<result >` line, you will figure out that it is working the same way thanks to the auto-mapping.